# spring data - hibernate exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Spring data jpa (1.11.0) throws an exception

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Properties;
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]

with hibernate-core:5.2.6

It was reported that [SPR-14365](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14365) was around this issue and has been closed, but the issue is still showing up.

Is there a workaround for this problem.

Comment: Have you check if you don't have multiple Hibernate jar in different version in your project ? You can check with `mvn dependency:tree` by example.

Comment: You are mixing hibernate versions, the core and entity manager version of the jar should match. You are mixing 5.0.11 and 5.2.6. Never mix versions of a framework.

Comment: I have changed the jar version to see if newer releases have resolved that issue,  hibernate-core:5.1.0 - hibernate-entityamanger:5.1.0 also gives exception  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException even when hibernate-core is on path.